# CSS: Using hsl variable in hsla?

Tags: css, css-variables

Say I have a CSS variable for an `hsl` defined as such:

```
--white-1: hsl(0deg 0% 100%);
```

Now, I want to use that same white, but at 50% opacity. So, something like this:

```
--white-2: hsla(0deg 0% 100% 50%);
```

Is there a way to use the first variable `--white-1` in the definition of the variable `--white-2`? I guess I want to do something like this:

```
--white-2: hsla(var(--white-1) 50%);
```

Is there a way to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: it should be noted that hsla() will become obsolete. hsl() accept a fourth argument for the opacity `hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 50%)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [the near future](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors) yes:

```
:root {
    --white-1: hsl(0deg 0% 100%);
    --white-2: hsl(from var(--white-1) h s l / 50%);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it like that

```css
:root {
    --white-1: 0deg, 0%, 100%;
    --white-2: var(--white-1), 0.5; 
}

.wrapper{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(155,194,89,1) 0%, rgba(194,166,89,1) 15%, rgba(89,179,194,1) 50%, rgba(155,194,89,1) 85%, rgba(194,89,183,1) 100%);
  padding: 3rem;
}

.div-1 {
    background: hsl(var(--white-1));
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.div-2 {
    background: hsla(var(--white-2));
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div-1">--white-1</div>
  <div class="div-2">--white-2</div>
</div>
```